# Need help searching for a correct switch

Tags: switches

I designed a PCB which uses switches. Sadly, I screwed up with the switching direction.

I bought these switches: [Klick here](https://www.amazon.de/Mts-103-Dreibeinigen-Kippschalter-Wippschalter-Schalter/dp/B07MCPB8B1/). The position corresponds to the connection table below:

[image: Button positions] [image]

The problem is that I need the connections the other way around. If the button is set to position 3, then pins 2 and 3 must connect. If the button is in position 1, then pins 1 and 2 should connect. The middle position does not matter / does not have to exist.

Does somebody know a switch with the same dimensions but opposite toggle? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: They might exist, but it would surprise me.  The connections are dictated by the toggle mechanism inside the switch and the spring loaded levers that make the contacts snap over for clean switching.  The reverse direction you want would need another lever to reverse the switching direction.  You might find a slide switch that would fit, but it won't look like a toggle switch.

Comment: Slide switch is a good hint, thank you! I will take a look.

Comment: While searching for spdt toggle switch, every result I got met your requirements, i can't find ones with your config, strange

Comment: can you provide a link? I only find switches corresponding to the table I posted...